# Why is my code reaching outside the intended tab for timestamps?

Tags: javascript, timestamp, google-sheets-query

Trying to figure this out. I had gotten an example of a timestamp script that will timestamp a specific column when another specific column gets edited. I tweaked a few things so that it would iterate through a list of columns to see if there was a change in any of those columns. The problem is that now it seems to timestamp whenever any other of the same columns in another tab are modified.

The only tab being modified that should trigger a timestamp (in column TStamp) is 'Roster_Gear_Ranks'.

```
function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var timezone = "GMT-5";
  var timestamp_format = "MM-dd-yyyy"; 
  var timeStampColName = "TStamp";  
const arrCol = ["Ranks","Ilvl","Legend","Back","Chest","Legs",
"Hands","Should","Head","Hds","Shld","Hnds","Lgs","Chst","Bck"];
  var arrLength = arrCol.length;
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('Roster_Gear_Ranks'); 
  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
    cell.setValue(date);

  for (var i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {  
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(arrCol[i]); updateCol = updateCol+1;
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) {     
  }
    cell()
    date()
 }
}
```

Comment: No offence, but the very bad code style is the source of bug. Even hard to review.

Comment: Also, could you please show where and how the `onEdit()` is being invoked from?

Comment: Yeah. As stated, I took it from someone else, and all I did was add the column array and the for loop to it. I'm really new to javascript. Only using it since googlesheet takes it. If you know a better, cleaner means to just iter through a list of columns to see if any changes were done and time stamp a specific column from the result of it, which also includes an exclusion from the header to be affected by this, let me know.